# Microsoft Word Footnote Number Deleted by A Contributer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a problem with Word that I have no idea how to address. A contributing author has gone through every single footnote in the document and deleted the **<sup>1</sup>automatic number** and replaced that with their own **1.** As such, when a new footnote is added all the numbers are completely wrong as there's no number to update. The footnote looks like `<deleted> 1. I typed '1.' in this` rather than **<sup>1.</sup> 1. Hi I'm a footnote where I typed '1.'**

I'm hoping there is a way to recreate the automatic number in the footnote so that we don't have to go through the entire document and replace each footnote to generate a new number. Any advice here would be appreciated. And if this isn't a feature I'm happy to submit it to Microsoft as it should be!

Example:

Hi I'm a paragraph<sup>1</sup> and I have some citations<sup>2</sup> and I want to add a new citations at the number two<sup>3</sup>

---

1 <strike><sup>1</sup></strike> I'm a footnote for one (Notice I don't have a super script)

<sup>2</sup> I'm the new footnote for two! (notice I'm a super script)

2 <strike><sup>3</sup></strike> I'm the old footnote which is three because someone deleted my number

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me on this one, it is definitely frustrating to watch my editor (for the fourth time this month) struggle with this problem. (We don't really have the strikeouts available otherwise I'd just "undelete it", this is just to illustrate the point).

And one last note (because it is late and I'm apparently loopy): We have access to 2013 and 2010. The editor prefers 2010 but 2013 solutions are completely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If I reproduce your problem with my 2010 I solve the issue as follows:

- copy a still existing footnote number in front of a footnote entry (e.g. insert a new footnote)
- paste it in front of another footnote entry which has no number anymore
- the inserted footnote number automatically updates to the correct number

I do not know why it works and I am irritated that it works ... . Probably it does not work in every situation.

Can other users reproduce this?